# Ionic "Seems to be a very old project file format - please open your project file in a more recent version of Xcode"

Tags: ionic-appflow

fastlane finished with errors relating to automatic_code_signing. I’m not sure what this means and how to fix it, but it’s an error I hadn’t gotten before. I’m on Ionic v3

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the iOS platform not being up to date.

> iOS builds including cordova-ios v4.5.5 or earlier will fail with this error in Appflow. This issue was corrected in cordova-ios v5.0.0. Updating to a current cordova-ios release will resolve the problem.

To remove and reinstall the iOS platform:

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@5.1.1 //the latest release of the current major version is recommended.
```

This 
example specifies the latest version at the time of writing

Source [here](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042199513-iOS-Builds-fail-with-error-Seems-to-be-a-very-old-project-file-format-please-open-your-project-file-in-a-more-recent-version-of-Xcode-)