# Fastlane Match strange old version issue

Tags: ios, match, fastlane

When I am trying to automate the signing process of my project by using Fastlane Match(via `update_code_signing_settings`) I get the next strange issue:

```
Seems to be a very old project file format - 
please open your project file in a more recent version of Xcode
```

My Fastfile looks like:

```
desc "Sync Signing..."
  lane :signing do
    sync_code_signing #match

    mapping = Actions.lane_context[
      SharedValues::MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING
    ]
    update_code_signing_settings(
      profile_name: mapping[ENV['MATCH_APP_IDENTIFIER']]
    )
  end
```

The thing is I am using the latest Xcode 12.5 version and I cannot find any fix for that in internet, so I thought maybe you could help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A similar issue: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171401/ionic-seems-to-be-a-very-old-project-file-format-please-open-your-project-fil

https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042199513-iOS-Builds-fail-with-error-Seems-to-be-a-very-old-project-file-format-please-open-your-project-file-in-a-more-recent-version-of-Xcode-

Comment: @Akif it is NOT similar. It's for Ionic. Also as I mentioned, I am using the recent version of XCode, 12.5.